# get preceding value based on priority

Tags: xslt

I've XML like below.

```
<root>
<title></title>
 <section>
    <title>
       <content-style font-style="bold">Short title</content-style>
    </title>
    <figure>
        <caption>
          <para></para>
        </caption>
        <graphic/>
    </figure>
    <para>
        <phrase>U2/1</phrase>
    </para>
 </section>
</root>
```

Here I've 2 questions.

1. I want to check if there is a `title` or `para`, preceding the `phrase`, if there is `title` i want to `apply-templates` on `title` node, else if there is `para` i want to `apply-templates` on `preceding para`. the priority is to be given to `title` if there is no title, then `para` should be consdered.
2. I've tried it using `<xsl:apply-templates select="preceding::title/node()[1]"/>`, but i was going to the title in `root` and printing blank.

please let me know were am i going wrong and how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the XSLT you did try. And also the expected output..

Comment: Why don't you write exactly what you said, using xsl:choose?